# Why do + and ~ affect Perl 6 junctions differently?

Tags: raku, perl6-junction

Add one to a junction of Ints:

```
put any( 1, 3, 7 ) + 1;
```

Now you have a junction of those Ints increased by one:

```
any(2, 4, 8)
```

So, `2 == any(2, 4, 8)` is true.

Make a junction of strings and append to those strings:

```
put any( <h H> ) ~ 'amadryas';
```

You get a different result that doesn't equal 'hamadryas' or 'Hamadryas':

```
any("h", "H")amadryas
```

I expected something like:

```
any( 'hamadryas', 'Hamadryas' );
```

What's the difference in these operations that gives them different behavior even though they should be similar?

Comment: First guess is that `&infix:«~»` has a `:(*@args --> Str:D)` candidate, while `&infix:«+»` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

on the High Sierra 10.13, put fails with:

```
put any( 1, 3, 7 ) + 1
```

This type cannot unbox to a native string: P6opaque, Junction
  in block  at  line 1

```
perl6 -v
```

This is Rakudo Star version 2017.10 built on MoarVM version 2017.10
implementing Perl 6.c.

Comment: Confirmed and reported: https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132549

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the filed bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=132549), as progressed by Zoffix++:

> Thank you for the report. lizmat++ fixed this.

The `put` routine does *not* explicitly handle Junction arguments. As [per design](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Autothreading), the end result is therefore a call to `put` for each of its elements:

```
put any( 1, 3, 7 ) + 1;        # 2␤4␤8
put any( <h H> ) ~ 'amadryas'; # hamadryas␤Hamadryas
```

Per design, the call order of the `put`s is indeterminate. So other runs of the same code, perhaps with later compilers, may result in:

```
put any( 1, 3, 7 ) + 1;        # 4␤8␤2
put any( <h H> ) ~ 'amadryas'; # Hamadryas␤hamadryas
```

In contrast to `put`, the `say` routine *does* special case Junctions. So the end result is just a single call to `say`:

```
say any( 1, 3, 7 ) + 1;        # any(2, 4, 8)
say any( <h H> ) ~ 'amadryas'; # any(hamadryas, Hamadryas)
```